# Github Actions: output variable is empty

Tags: android, github, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions

I created an action that publishes my app apk.
Now im tying to handle version naming on release, but im stuck bc output variable is empty .

The action.yml is:

```
name: Android CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  apk:
    name: Generate the apk file
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      version: ${{ steps.getVersion.outputs.version }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: gradle
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
    - name : Upload APK file
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
        name: apk
        path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
    - name: Get app version
      id: getVersion
      run: |
        echo "::set-output name=version::$(./gradlew printVersionName)"
  release:
    name: Release the apk
    needs: apk
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download APK from build
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: apk
      - name: Create Release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: Release${{ needs.apk.outputs.version }}
          release_name: Release ${{ needs.apk.outputs.version }}
      - name: Upload Release APK
        id: upload_release_asset
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1.0.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: apk/app-debug.apk
          asset_name: takeThatProduct.apk
          asset_content_type: application/zip
```

The step to get version works well, is defined in my build.gradle:
[image: As you can see, returns 0.3 version]

But when i get the output variable in the release job, its empty:

[image]

So, the release gets created buy with no version number. New releases fail because the name already exists.
[image]

Comment: What is returned by the `$(./gradlew printVersionName)` command in the **Get app version** step, if you try to print the result before setting it in the output?

Comment: think it was returning :
'> Task :app:printVersionName
0.3'

instead of '0.3' 

don´t know why my gradle method was doing that

Answer (score 0):

Changed my action using this action: [apk-info-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/apk-info-action)

```
name: Android CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  apk:
    name: Generate the apk file
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      version: ${{ steps.getVersion.outputs.version }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: gradle
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build
    - name : Upload APK file
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
        name: apk
        path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
    - name: Get apk info
      id: apk-info
      uses: hkusu/apk-info-action@v1
      with:
        apk-path: app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
    - name: Export apk info
      id: getVersion
      run: |
        echo "::set-output name=version::${{ steps.apk-info.outputs.version-name }}"
  release:
    name: Release the apk
    needs: apk
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download APK from build
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: apk
      - name: Create Release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          tag_name: Release${{ needs.apk.outputs.version }}
          release_name: Release ${{ needs.apk.outputs.version }}
      - name: Upload Release APK
        id: upload_release_asset
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1.0.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: apk/app-debug.apk
          asset_name: takeThatProduct.apk
          asset_content_type: application/zip
```